# simple join sql ambiguous column

Tags: sql, join, where-clause, ambiguous

I'm getting an ambiguous column error? Even though they are exactly the same like all the other columns that I selected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [date], [problem], [companyprofit], [fixtime]
FROM [fixandresponse]  , [netprofit] 
WHERE [fixandresponse].[date] = [netprofit].[date]
```

Comment: First of all, don't use comma, use proper join to join table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because two table have a same column name: date.

You can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [fixandresponse].[date], [problem], [companyprofit], [fixtime]
FROM [fixandresponse]  , [netprofit] 
WHERE [fixandresponse].[date] = [netprofit].[date]
```

Also, you should use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.[date], F...., N.... -- get column from two table
FROM [fixandresponse] F
  INNER JOIN [netprofit] N
    ON F.[date] = N.[date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thus Test

```
Select distinct f.date, f.problem, f.companyprofit, f.fixtime    
from fixandresponse f, netprofit n    
Where f.date = n.date
```